# Change file upload size in linux server

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have to upload a pdf file with 34MB. My site is in Linux with php. But my site support only 8MB. (I know this from phpinfo). How I increase the size? I heared that we can change it in php.ini through. htaccess. But where I get php.ini? How I change the size?. Does any one give me a solution ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are multiple settings that can affect the maximum file upload size:

**PHP_INI_PERDIR:** The following settings can be set in php.ini, .htaccess or httpd.conf:

[upload_max_filesize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize)
The maximum size of an uploaded file.

[post_max_size](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size)
Sets maximum size of post data allowed. To upload large files, this value must be larger than upload_max_filesize. If memory limit is enabled by your configure script, memory_limit also affects file uploading.

[max_input_time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-time)
This sets the maximum time in seconds a script is allowed to parse input data, like POST, GET and file uploads.

**PHP_INI_ALL:** The following settings can be set in php.ini, .htaccess, httpd.conf, or with [ini_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php):

[max_execution_time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time)
This sets the maximum time in seconds a script is allowed to run before it is terminated by the parser.  If this limit is too low, your script will terminate before a large file has had time to upload.

[memory_limit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit)
This sets the maximum amount of memory in bytes that a script is allowed to allocate.  If memory limit is enabled by your configure script, memory_limit also affects file uploading. Generally speaking, `memory_limit` should be larger than `post_max_size`.

**POST upload method**
When uploading files via the POST method, you also need to set `MAX_FILE_SIZE` in your HTML form.  See this for more details:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

**Shared hosting**
If you are using shared hosting, it is unlikely that you will be able to access the system php.ini file.  However, you can set the values in .htaccess or in a per-directory php.ini file.  Some shared hosting providers may prevent you from doing this, so you will need to check if this is the case.

**.htaccess**
Here's a sample .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_value upload_max_filesize 70M
  php_value post_max_size 80M
  php_value memory_limit 90M
  php_value max_execution_time 240
  php_value max_input_time 240
</IfModule>
```

**Per-directory php.ini**
The above settings can also be changed in a per-directory php.ini file.  Again, the ability to do this may be restricted by your hosting provder.  For more information on this, see here:

http://www.askapache.com/php/custom-phpini-tips-and-tricks.html

**Changeable:**
For a description of the PHP_INI_* modes, which show where configuration directives may be set, see here:
http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php

Comment: *memory\_limit* does not affect the maximum size of an file upload.

Comment: @Gumbo: It affects `post_max_size`.  See those documentation here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size  I have updated the answer to make this clearer.

Comment: There may also be limits set at the webserver level.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in .htaccess:

```
php_value memory_limit 64M
php_value upload_max_filesize 32M
php_value post_max_size 32M
php_value max_execution_time 600
php_value max_input_time 600
```

or php.ini (see variables above)

Comment: The documentation is a little spread out, but `upload_max_filesize`, `post_max_size` and `max_input_time` cannot be set with `ini_set()`. See [Where a configuration setting may be set](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php), [File Uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.file-uploads), [Data Handling](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.data-handling) and [Runtime Configuration](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#info.configuration) for more information.

Comment: Sorry for my incorrect tip, i'll edit my answer. Btw i'll go with .htaccess anyway.